# cannot decode block 0 to find the output address. I can decode much higher blocks. what am i missing?

Tags: genesis-block, p2pk

Can you please decode block 0 output transaction manually showing me how to get the output address namely: 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa

Comment: How are you trying to decode it? There isn't anything special about block 0, you can decode it like any other block.

Comment: I could not find the address of the output transaction. can you show me how you get to the address (in my original post)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I figured out my mistake. Earlier bitcoin blocks stored the public key in the signature instead of its hash.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Note that this depends on your definition of "address". These days an address is a way of representing a specific output script, and under that definition the genesis block's coinbase transaction's output simply has **no address**. The  1... address shown in many explorers is historical, from a time when addresses were just a "key identifier".